# PHP IP Address Capture Statement

Tags: php, ip-address, capture

I am trying to make it so the content is only for my IP address, and someone elses.  I tried:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($ip = "FirstIp" && $ip="SecondIp") {
echo "Protect Content";
} else {
echo "You do not have permission to look at this.  Your IP has been recorded. $ip";
$fileofips="list.txt";
$ip = "$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";

$file=fopen($fileofips, 'a');
fwrite($f, $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]);

fclose($f);
}
?>
```

And it won't even capture intruding IPs.  Please tune up the code ;P

Comment: "Please tune up the code ;P" No. Tell us what's not working and what you have tried. Look at other StackOverflow questions about writing to files.

Comment: The last days I have noticed, that lot's of people lack the understanding of `||` and `&&` uses ...

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($ip = "FirstIp" && $ip="SecondIp") {
```

A single equals sign is an assignment, not a comparison. Also, you probably meant `||`; `$ip` can't be two things at once.

```
if($ip === "FirstIP" || $ip === "SecondIP") {
```

---

Also, you probably want newlines between your IPs in the file, so add a `\n`. Also also, putting a variable in double quotes like this:

```
$ip = "$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
```

is pointless. Use the variable.

Comment: @minitech You don't need to use tripple = in this case. You are not looking for a boolean value, just for a simple string.

Comment: @DainisAbols: I like it because it's stricter. Just because I don't need to doesn't mean I shouldn't.

Comment: Not really, if the IP value for some reason is set to `0` you will still get true, even though you don't need it to be true. In this case you are strictly looking for a string value, not for a string to be true.

Comment: @DainisAbols: No, really. It's a coding convention, and I'm perfectly happy with it, thanks.

Comment: @DainisAbols: No, I'm not misusing anything, and I have no idea what you're talking about "check for boolean" versus "check for an actual value". I think you need to read the docs again.

Comment: "that it's bad practise to check for boolean" --- are you sure you use correct terms?

Comment: PS: even though personally I use `==` in such cases - there is absolutely nothing wrong with `===`

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` statement is overwriting the `$ip` variable because you're using a single `=`; Change it to `==`, and also the `&&` to an `||` (one IP can't be two at the same time):

```
if ($ip == "FirstIp" || $ip == "SecondIp") {
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Sparkups answer;

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (in_array($ip, ["FirstIp", "SecondIp", "ThirdIp"])) {
    // add hidden content here 
} else {
    echo "Access denied";
}
```

Or, even better, if the IP is not in the Array, post a message and exit. just do the following:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (!in_array($ip, ["FirstIp", "SecondIp", "ThirdIp"])) {
    echo "Access denied";
    exit; 
}
```

OR include a 404 page to make it appear that nothing is there:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (!in_array($ip, ["FirstIp", "SecondIp", "ThirdIp"])) {
    include('404.html');
    exit; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** could be more suitable in some cases :

```
if (in_array($ip, ["FirstIp", "SecondIp", "ThirdIp"])) {
    echo "Protect Content";
} else {
    // 
}
```

Comment: This is missing ) at "ThirdIp"]))